# Finishing Activity after PictureCallback

Tags: android

I have a CameraPreviewActivity which is much similar to what I got here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

I declared a Handler to capture an image after 5 seconds, in order for Activity Screen to load fully / stablize.

```
Handler aHandler = new Handler();
aHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {                                                     
        mPreview.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, myPictureCallback_jpeg);
        // finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```

How do I end this Activity once myPictureCallback_jpeg has been called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, Your activity context and try to finish,

```
ActivityName.finish();
```

or

```
<activityContext>.finish(); // Its for example..
```

Comment: How do I get my activity context? One is the activity class (CameraPreview.java).. another is not an activity class (Preview.java).

Comment: public class CameraPreview extends Activity <<

Comment: I need to call finish() in Preview.java where myPictureCallback is located at. I do not have the reference to the Activity context.

Comment: The code has already past context over to preview class. So I just have to declare a global Context datatype to use it?

Comment: Ok. My code backbone is from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html The context is only in the constructor, Preview(Context context) { .. so from here I just add a global variable to use it in my other methods?

Comment: Ok, declare Context con; in you Preview class with other variables, and in your Preview class constructor con=context; then use con.finish()... Try this..

Comment: Ok. I am able to get this working by declaring a global Context con; and calling ((Activity) con).finish(); thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement an interface for callback.

```
public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements ActionCallBack {
      ...
      ...
      ...
    public void afterActionPerformed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.finish();
    }
      ...
}

interface ActionCallBack {
    public void afterActionPerformed(); 
}

public class ActivityCallBack {
    private ActionCallBack cb;

    public ActivityCallBack(CameraPreview cp) { 
        cb = cp;
    }
    public void callBackMethod()
    {       
        cb.afterActionPerformed();   
    } 
}

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    ActivityCallBack acb;
        ...
        ...
    Preview(Context context) {
         super(context);
         //con = context;       
         acb = new ActivityCallBack((CameraPreview) context);
    }
    ...
    ...

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_jpeg = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
            String fileName = storeByteImage(imageData,
                    Integer.parseInt(imageQuality));

            // End the activity
            //((Activity) con).finish();
            acb.callBackMethod();

        }
    };
```